# new docker container for every user

Tags: apache, docker

I am building a "hackme" challenge. Users can hack there way into the website and gain root access.

I made this in docker containers to prevent users from harming the host or each others game play(container).

I can't just redirect it to a different port for every user because users could just port scan the server and find the different containers.

What i want is http://example.com/challange1/A1B2C3
were "A1B2C3" is the unique identifier for their own container.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you need to give access to it over http? If so, you need some proxy run on your side which will redirect subdomains into proper containers, but it means that the hackme is http port based?

Comment: yes this part is http port based

Comment: For example with nginx and nginxproxy you are able to redirect port 80 for different subdomains to different group of containers. For example staging.example.com to staging-main, and test.example.com to test-main. Probably it is possible with differetnt adresses like you want.

Comment: With nginx itself you can redirect traffic from different URLs to some given containers.

Answer (score 0):

With nginx you can do following - you can rewrite the requestes for given paths like here: https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0#step-7----rewriting-requests

Where the names here are the existing run containers.

```
server {
listen       ...;
...
location /a1b2c3 {
    proxy_pass http://a1b2c3:8080;
}

location /a2b1c4 {
    proxy_pass http://a2b1c4:8080;
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Jwilder/Nginx for this task. Just start the different
containers with "random" Subdomains.

Start Nginx/Jwilder

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Start your Containers

```
   for i in {1..5}
    do
      docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo-$i.bar.com mycontainer
    done
```

Jwilder/Nginx will be updated on every container started, and will register
the new VHOST.

Comment: But it is finally pointing to the same container for all unique URLs, isnt't it?

Comment: No every container has his unique subdomain, nginx is pointing to every single container.